# Changing Picture Of an existing gui_Control , using the HWND

Tags: autohotkey

Changing the picture of an existing Gui control, by using the control's HWND, makes no difference:

```
Gui, Add, Picture, HwnddestId1 ,F:\caching_fig1.png
Gui, Show, x0 y0 w800 h900, Title
GuiControl,, destId1, F:\custom_errordocs.png
```

Using an associated variable works though:

```
Gui, Add, Picture, vMyPicture,F:\caching_fig1.png
Gui, Show, x0 y0 w800 h900, Title
GuiControl,, MyPicture, F:\custom_errordocs.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find it in documentation but finally found it when testing different combinations. You have to put HWND in %% while for var you don't need it.

```
Gui, Add, Picture, HwnddestId1 ,F:\caching_fig1.png
Gui, Show, x0 y0 w800 h900, Title
GuiControl,, %destId1%, F:\custom_errordocs.png
```